# How to programmatically change zoom in ImageView.imshow

Tags: julia

Based on the ImageView.imshow documentation here: 
https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl

it looks like it should be possible to change the zoom rectangle of an imshow viewer programmatically, however I have not been able to find a concrete example of how to do this and I'm not sure how to create an object of the correct type to send to the signal.

If I do this:

```
guidict = imshow( videog )
zr = guidict["roi"]["zoomregion"]
zr
```

I get:

```
10: "input-21" = ZoomRegion{RInt64}(XY(1..640, 1..480), XY(1..640, 1..480)) ZoomRegion{RInt64}
```

Aside from the complexity of the types, I don't understand why the zoom region should need to be specified twice as it is here.

In any case if I do:

```
push!( zr, ZoomRegion{RInt64}( XY(200..280, 280..360), XY(200:280, 280..360) ) )
```

(where I'm trying to set the zoom to 200:280 in X and 280:360 in Y)

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: promotion of types UnitRange{Int64} and IntervalSets.Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64} failed to change any arguments
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String, ::String, ::String) at ./error.jl:42
 [2] sametype_error(::Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},IntervalSets.Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64}}) at ./promotion.jl:308
 [3] not_sametype(::Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},IntervalSets.Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64}}, ::Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},IntervalSets.Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64}}) at ./promotion.jl:302
 [4] promote at ./promotion.jl:285 [inlined]
 [5] XY(::UnitRange{Int64}, ::IntervalSets.Interval{:closed,:closed,Int64}) at /home/flynn/.julia/packages/GtkReactive/2h7NX/src/graphics_interaction.jl:93
 [6] top-level scope at none:0
```

Does anyone have a concrete example of how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zoom region is made of two components, full view and current view. When you're pushing to the signal you are only moving the current view [which handles the zooming].

You can use unit ranges when pushing, like this

```
push!(zr, (200:280, 280:360))
```

To reset back to the full view you just need to then do this

```
push!(zr, zr.value.fullview)
```